# Excel and .net ODC connection

Tags: c#, .net, excel

For logging purposes I am trying to get data from a rockwell PLC and use them in a .net application.
The PLC programmer has a way to extract data using excel external connections

Example:

`=@RsLinx|TSK_B!'AlarnLogFifo[280].Date[0]'`

However I am struggeling to do this directly in my application.
My current workaround is open the excel file every 5min, update the links and extract the data.

looking at the .xml file from excel did not help me much either

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<externalLink xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
-<ddeLink ddeTopic="TSK_B" ddeService="RsLinx" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
-<ddeItems>
+<ddeItem advise="1" name="AlarnLogFifo[280].Color">
+<ddeItem advise="1" name="AlarnLogFifo[280].Date[0]">
```

how can I use this same methode from excel in a .net application?
I do not know / see the connection string to open a connection.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you say you have an ODC file somewhere? Open it in notepad; it's just a conenction string inside it. No, wait.. ignore me.. I'm thinking of a UDL. What do you see in "existing connections" on the data tab if you open the ODC in excel? If you choose an entry and get "properties" then "definition" - is the connection string in there?

Comment: @CaiusJard if i go to data and then edit links, there is nothing.
under data Connections i can see the same as in the excel cells but without the @

Comment: [ODC file format tech info](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-ODCFF/%5BMS-ODCFF%5D.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Actually, if you have an ODC file, do open it in notepad.. it's not just a connection string like a UDL is, but it may well have a conn str somewhere inside it

Comment: I do not have an ODC file, all I have is this working excel file.